# Join between two tabales in differenet databases using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have two database servers, both Oracle. suppose we have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_ONE E1
JOIN TABLE_TWO E2 ON E1.TWO = E2.ID
```

and `TABLE_ONE` is on database server #1 `TABLE_TWO` on #2.
Now I want a mechanism that without changing query(which is very time consuming) the hibernate acquire the result. Note that `spring framework` is involved too.

Comment: Hibernate does not supporting joining across multiple "physical" database instances

Comment: Just google that :-) honestly not too much

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma any solutions for such a situation?

Comment: You could use database LINK to perform joining https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=994403&sid=c54ddfe21ace9706fd9fddd4a335c43e

Comment: Is there any intermediate layer ( say a software ) that hibernate can connect to it and that god blessed layer brings hibernate the result?

Comment: Are you able to execute that query from your DB admin tool? I suppose you aren't. If not, there's little you can do with Hibernate, I think.

Comment: @XtremeBiker no I cant't. there is limited privileges

Answer (score 1):

Use [oracle dblink](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_create_database_link.htm) and create synonym for that table or create view for that table to be able to reference it in hibernate.

Comment: After consulting with db admin, I realized that db link is not allowed based on our certain concerns

Comment: How were you performing this query till now? If you can run it from within any sql tool (sqldeveloper, toad, ...), then you can run it as native query. If you are using spring data jpa create custom repository and run it from within tehere. Try to look [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/).

Comment: I used to run this query in a single databse, now the policy is that we have multiple servers and I'm looking for an easy, efficient way with minimum changes.

Comment: So there are only two options for you...one mentioned before with dblink or you can have two entitymanagers (each for different database) and create two separate queries (so no more joins between tables). But if I can suggest...go for option 1 as it is easier  if there are no security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not support joining multiple physical databases. You can make it for two schemas under the same database possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database link, if your dba doesn't allow that then you have to do some kind of client side joining and that will probably be slow. Talk to your boss.